# I get a Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Tags: php

**The Error**

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\checklogin.php on line 11

**Code**

```
isset(md5($_POST['password'])) ? $password = $_POST['password'] : $password = '';
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please don't use `md5` to store passwords. Have a look at [hashing passwords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php)

Comment: You should not be using MD5 for passwords. PHP has quite mature password hash verification with [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Answer (score 2):

It is giving you the error because you are using a function inside of isset()

You should use it this way -

```
$password = isset($_POST['password'])) ? md5( $_POST['password'] ) : '';
```

In ternary operator, it returns the value according to the condition true or false

Comment: Thanks for your help .|
and I get this error 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\checklogin.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\checklogin.php on line 20 
My code on line 20

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_member 
      WHERE email ='".$_POST['email']."' 
      AND password ='".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
 //count result data